# Predict batches using Tensorflow Data API and Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Suppose I have a dataset and a Keras Model. The dataset has been divided into batches using `batch()` in tf Dataset API. Now I am seeking an efficient and clean way to do batch predictions for all testing samples.

I have tried the following code and it works.

```
batch_size = 32
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
predictions = keras_model.predict(dataset, steps=math.ceil(num_testing_samples / batch_size))
```

I wonder is there any more efficient and elegant approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

## TF >= 1.14.0

You can just set `steps=None`. From the official documentation of `tf.keras.Model.predict()`:

> If x is a tf.data dataset and steps is None, predict will run until the input dataset is exhausted.

Just make sure that your `dataset` object is not in repeat mode and you are good to go :).

## TF 1.12.0 & 1.13.0

The support for `tf.data.Dataset` with `tf.keras` is very poor in these versions. The `tf.data.Dataset` object is transformed into an iterator [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L937), which then triggers an error [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L892) if you didn't set the `steps` argument. This is patched in 1.14.0.

Comment: If I set steps=None, the following error would appear:
ValueError: When using iterators as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument. The version of tensorflow I am using is 1.12.0